# Mixing the characters in a String (changing order of binary results)

Tags: java, loops, binary

I am doing an exercise with this set forth: Given a natural number x > 0 with n bits, we denote with xn−1… x0 its representation in base 2. For example, x = 8 in base 2 is 1000, so x3 = 1 and x2 = x1 = x0 = 0.

Write a program to mix the base 2 representations of two given natural numbers x and y with the same number of bits n. That is, print xn−1 yn−1 … x0 y0.

I have a program that calculates the binary expression of 2 int numbers and prints both binaries together. What I need to do is change the order of the 0s and 1s.
For example, I input 2 numbers (10, 15) and I will get 1010 1111, but I want to mix these numbers in this order:

1. At first I want the first digit of each binary (11)
2. Then the second number of each binary (01)
3. The third number of each binary (11)
4. The fourth number of each binary (01)

I have this code that prints the binary of 2 decimal numbers, but it's missing the mixing part. I've already tried to work with charAt (that's why I'm using Strings for the binary numbers) but I could'nt make it work.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
        String bin = "";
        String bin2 = "";
        if (num > 0) {
            while (num > 0) {
                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                    bin = "0" + bin;
                } else {
                    bin = "1" + bin;
                }
                num = (int) num / 2;
            }
        } else if (num == 0) {
            bin = "0";
        }

        if (num2 > 0) {
            while (num2 > 0) {
                if (num2 % 2 == 0) {
                    bin2 = "0" + bin2;
                } else {
                    bin2 = "1" + bin2;
                }
                num2 = (int) num2 / 2;
            }
        } else if (num2 == 0) {
            bin2 = "0";
        } 

        System.out.print(bin+bin2);
```

Comment: is it a requirement to do the mixing part on fly, or you can do it after bringing your numbers to base 2?

Comment: I think I need to bring my numbers to base 2 to mix them, if that's what you mean.

Comment: What I wanted to say is you have 2 options. First one is to bring your numbers to base 2, get 2 strings, and mix those strings, or do the mixing part on fly, when you are calculating the values.

Comment: What if the string representation of your binaries have different length, e.g `2= 10 and 128 = 10000000` how do you want to mix them?

Comment: This is not specified in the exercise, but it just have to change the order of the same number of digits for each binary. If binary 1 has 4 digits and binary 2 has 5, I will just change the matchig amout of digits (4).

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that both numbers should have the same length in binary representation, here are 2 ways you can do the mixing.

This one is converting both numbers to bits, and then does the mixing

```java
class Base2Mix1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int first = 10;
        int second = 15;

        String firstBits = baseTwoRepresentation(first);
        String secondBits = baseTwoRepresentation(second);

        int length = firstBits.length();

        char[] mixed = new char[length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            mixed[i * 2] = firstBits.charAt(i);
            mixed[i * 2 + 1] = secondBits.charAt(i);
        }

        System.out.println(new String(mixed));
    }

    private static String baseTwoRepresentation(int num) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(num > 0) {
            sb.append(num % 2);
            num /= 2;
        }
        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }

}
```

And this is the version of doing the mix part during the conversion

```java
class Base2Mix2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int first = 10;
        int second = 15;

        String mixedBits = mixedBits(first, second);
        System.out.println(mixedBits);
    }

    private static String mixedBits(int first, int second) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while(first > 0 && second > 0) {
            stringBuilder
                    .append(second % 2)
                    .append(first % 2);

            first /= 2;
            second /= 2;
        }

        return stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me but I can't use methods or Stringbuilder for that. I am only working with loops.

Comment: Well you can use String then